# Return of response is different from Interface but still works

Tags: typescript, express

I'm trying to do a GET to themoviedb API, working with Express and TypeScript.

I want that to make sure that response.json() will be like the interface ApiResponse. so to make sure it's working i'm changing success from boolean to number and testing it. As it will be always a boolean, it should throw an error, but  instead, it's still returning it susccessfully.

```
app.get('/api/data', async (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/authentication';
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/json',
      Authorization:
        'AUTHORIZATION',
    },
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    const json = (await response.json()) as ApiResponse;
    console.log(json);
    res.json(json); // Puedes enviar la respuesta al cliente si es necesario
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('error:', err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

interface ApiResponse {
  success: number;
  status_code: number;
  status_message: string;
}
```

Also tried with Promise but still can't work.

Comment: The types are erased in transpilation, leaving only JavaScript. TypeScript **cannot** do anything at runtime, it doesn't exist. (Also it seems like the content of your payload is what the response object already exposes, which seems like pointless repetition.)